# How to produce 64 bit masks?

Tags: c++, 64-bit, bit-shift, bitmask

Based on the following simple program the bitwise left shift operator works only for 32 bits. Is it true?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;


    int main(void)
    {
        long long currentTrafficTypeValueDec;
        int input;
        cout << "Enter input:" << endl;
        cin >> input;
        currentTrafficTypeValueDec = 1 << (input - 1); 
        cout << currentTrafficTypeValueDec << endl;
        cout << (1 << (input - 1)) << endl;

        return 0;

    }
```

The output of the program:

```
Enter input:
30
536870912
536870912

Enter input:
62
536870912
536870912
```

How could I produce 64-bit masks?

Comment: If you're including `<iostream>`, this is a C++ question!

Comment: Except that long long is not currently part of C++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make input an long long too, and use 1LL << (input - 1LL).  Here your shift is computed on 32 bits, and converted to 64 bits when stored in currentTrafficTypeValueDec.